# how to generate Serial numbers +Add 1 in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know we can generate row_number in select statement. But row_number starts from 1, I need to generate from 2 and onwards.

example

```
party_code
----------
R06048
R06600
R06791
(3 row(s) affected)
I want it like

party_code serial number
---------- -------------
R06048       2
R06600       3
R06791       4
```

Current I am using below select statement for generate regular row number.

```
 SELECT party_code, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY party_code) AS [serial number]
FROM myTable
ORDER BY party_code
```

How can modify above select statement and start from 2?

Comment: ooh, you're gonna kick yourself...

Comment: Did you try `ROW_NUMBER() + 1`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SELECT party_code, 1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY party_code) AS [serial number]
FROM myTable
ORDER BY party_code
```

to add: `ROW_NUMBER()` has an unusual syntax, and can be confusing with the various `OVER` and `PARTITION BY` clauses, but when all is said and done it is still just a function with a numeric return value, and that return value can be manipulated in the same way as any other number.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about SQL Server but either one of these will work:

```
SELECT party_code, 1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY party_code) AS [serial number]
FROM myTable
ORDER BY party_code
```

OR

```
SELECT party_code, serial_numer + 1 AS [serial number] FROM
(SELECT party_code, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY party_code) AS [serial number]
FROM myTable)
ORDER BY party_code
```