# Sequence / serial no in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

My question is similar to [how to generate Serial numbers +Add 1 in select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600022/how-to-generate-serial-numbers-add-1-in-select-statement)

But I need the seq as below in Oracle sql

table 1 data:

```
facility    store     stop_seq
32          729        1
32          380        2
32          603        3
12          722        4
12          671        5
48          423        6
```

I need result as below:

```
facility   res_seq
32          1
12          2
48          3
```

Here `res_seq` should be order by based on stop_seq in tabel 1

Please help

Comment: The linked answer will work in Oracle as well if you replace the non-standard name `[serial number]` with a valid SQL identifier.

Comment: What is facility 32 would have stop_seqs 1, 5 and 10? What would that do to its res_seq?

Answer (score 0):

```
select facility, row_number() over(order by max(stop_seq)) res_seq
from your_tab group by facility;
```

`ROW_NUMBER` is explained in the link posted in the question

Analytic functions are performed after GROUP BY, so in this query the data is aggregated by `facility` and then row numbers are assigned

Comment: I suggest you add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are sometimes good enough, but code+explanation answers are always better