# weighted regression in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, regression, weighted

I'm new to SQL, so waiting for someone to shed me some lights hopefully.  We got a stored procedure in place using the simple linear regression.  Now I want to apply some weighting using a discount factor of lamda, i.e. 1, lamda, lamda^2, ..., lamda^n, while n is the length of the original series.

How should I generate the discounted weight series and apply to the current code structure below?
...

```
SUM((OASSpline-OASPriorSpline) * (AdjOASDolDur-AdjOASPriorDolDur))/SUM(SQUARE((AdjOASDolDur-AdjOASPriorDolDur))) as Beta, /* Beta = Sxy/Sxx */
SUM(SQUARE((AdjOASDolDur-AdjOASPriorDolDur))) as Sxx,
SUM((OASSpline-OASPriorSpline) * (AdjOASDolDur-AdjOASPriorDolDur)) as Sxy
```

...

e.g.

If I set discount factor (lamda) = 0.99, my weighting array should be formed generated automatically using the length of 10 from my series:

```
OASSpline = [1.11,1.45,1.79, 2.14, 2.48, 2.81,3.13,3.42,3.70,5.49]
AdjOASDolDur = [0.75,1.06,1.39, 1.73, 2.10, 2.48,2.85,3.20,3.52,3.61]
OASPriorSpline = 5.49
AdjOASPriorDolDur = 5.61
Weight = [1,0.99,0.9801,0.970299,0.96059601,0.9509900,  0.941480149,0.932065348,0.922744694,0.913517247]
```

The weighted linear regression should return a beta of 0.81243398, while the current simple linear regression should return a beta of 0.81164174.

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Comment: Thanks for your attention, a_horse.  We are using Microsoft SQL.  Does that answer your DBMS question?

Comment: Agree with @a_horse_with_no_name, expected output and sample data is helpful. Many people know SQL but I for one have no idea what "discount factor", "lamda", "weighted linear regression" or "beta" are! :)

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.  I added some inputs and expected output in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab.

You could look at this [article dealing generating sequence numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600022/how-to-generate-serial-numbers-add-1-in-select-statement) and then use the current row number generated as an exponent. Does that work? I think a fair few are bamboozled by the request.